# Websocket new frame byte

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, websocket

I am currently writing a Visual Basic script that opens a TcpListener on local machine ip (127.0.0.1) and on port 8181. I connect to my websocket server (via the AcceptSocket method) from Google Chrome. From Chrome i do a send request to the server and the server can read it and everything. When I send the message back (like an echo) I can send it the first time but the second time I get an error:

`Received unexpected continuation frame.`

What i need is a CByte that tells the frame to start a new one or end the open one (without closing the socket connection)

Is this achieveable and if so what is the solution?

I call the Sub with `SendMessage(sck, "test")`

Here is the code for my message sender:

```
Sub SendMessage(sck As Socket, message As String)
    Dim rawData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message)
    Dim frameCount = 0
    Dim frame(10) As Byte
    frame(0) = CByte(129)

    If rawData.Length <= 125 Then
        frame(1) = CByte(rawData.Length)
        frameCount = 2
    ElseIf rawData.Length >= 126 AndAlso rawData.Length <= 65535 Then
        frame(1) = CByte(126)
        Dim len = CByte(rawData.Length)
        frame(2) = CByte(((len >> 8) & CByte(255)))
        frame(3) = CByte((len & CByte(255)))
        frameCount = 4
    Else
        frame(1) = CByte(127)
        Dim len = CByte(rawData.Length)
        frame(2) = CByte(((len >> 56) & CByte(255)))
        frame(3) = CByte(((len >> 48) & CByte(255)))
        frame(4) = CByte(((len >> 40) & CByte(255)))
        frame(5) = CByte(((len >> 32) & CByte(255)))
        frame(6) = CByte(((len >> 24) & CByte(255)))
        frame(7) = CByte(((len >> 16) & CByte(255)))
        frame(8) = CByte(((len >> 8) & CByte(255)))
        frame(9) = CByte((len & CByte(255)))
        frameCount = 10
    End If
    Dim bLength = frameCount + rawData.Length
    Console.WriteLine(frameCount)
    Console.WriteLine(rawData.Length)
    Dim reply(bLength + 1) As Byte

    Dim bLim = 0
    For i = 0 To frameCount - 1
        Console.WriteLine(bLim)
        reply(bLim) = frame(i)
        bLim += 1
    Next

    For i = 0 To rawData.Length - 1
        Console.WriteLine(bLim)
        reply(bLim) = rawData(i)
        bLim += 1
    Next
    For i = 0 To reply.Length - 1
        Console.WriteLine("Byte: " & reply(i))
        Console.WriteLine("Char: " & CByte(reply(i)))
    Next
    sck.Send(reply, reply.Length, 0)
End Sub
```

Update:

After changing the line `Dim reply(bLength + 1) As Byte` to `Dim reply(bLength) As Byte` i dont get the continuous frame error, but instead i get a new error:

`A server must not mask any frames that it sends to the client.`

Hopefully this information can point to the problem.

Update 2:

Below is the entire client Sub the does everything with the clients. From accept to handshake to message stuff.

```
Private Sub clientStarter(ByVal sck As Socket)
    Dim netStream As New NetworkStream(sck)
    Dim netReader As New IO.StreamReader(netStream)
    Dim netWriter As New IO.StreamWriter(netStream)

    Dim key As String = ""

    Console.WriteLine("Accept new connection ...")

    '' Reading handshake message
    While (True)
        Dim line As String = netReader.ReadLine()
        If line.Length = 0 Then
            Exit While
        End If

        If (line.StartsWith("Sec-WebSocket-Key: ")) Then
            key = line.Split(":")(1).Trim()
        End If

        Console.WriteLine("Data: " & line)
    End While

    '' Calculate accept-key
    key += "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"
    key = getSHA1Hash(key)

    '' Response handshake message
    Dim response As String
    response = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols" & vbCrLf
    response &= "Upgrade: websocket" & vbCrLf
    response &= "Connection: Upgrade" & vbCrLf
    response &= "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " & key & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    netWriter.Write(response)
    netWriter.Flush()
    Dim dataSent As [Byte]() = Nothing
    Dim dataRecieved(1024) As [Byte]
    Dim bytes As Int32
    Console.WriteLine(dataRecieved)
    Dim message As String = Nothing
    While (True)
        If (sck.Connected = False) Then
            Exit While
        End If
        bytes = sck.Receive(dataRecieved, dataRecieved.Length, 0)
        'Console.WriteLine(bytes)
        While (bytes > 0)
            Console.WriteLine("recieved Data")
            message = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dataRecieved, 0, bytes)
            Console.WriteLine(bytes)
            bytes = 0
            If (bytes = 0) Then
                Console.WriteLine("test")
                Console.WriteLine(message)

                dataSent = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message, 0, bytes)
                SendMessage(sck, "test")
                message = Nothing
            End If
        End While
    End While
End Sub
```

Update 3 (solution):

I have figured out my problem. By changing `frame(1) = CByte(rawData.Length)` to `frame(1) = CByte(rawData.Length + 1)` it incorperates the end 0 byte and now the proper length of the message is correct and rids me of my masking problem. I guess the end of the message byte is supposed to be included in the message length.

Comment: Is [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490820/websockets-unresolvable-received-unexpected-continuation-frame-error) relevant at all?

Comment: Can you post your message sending code?

Comment: @HartleySan This may be relevant but i highly doubt it. My handshake response is good. The last line of my response is `"Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " & key & vbCrLf & vbCrLf` then it gets sent.

Comment: So you're saying that the handshake is successful, but everything after that doesn't work? Are you properly unmasking (i.e., decoding) the data sent from the client?

Comment: @HartleySan I am sure the handshake is good because i can send the first message and recieve it in chrome but the second one i send and try to recieve in chrome is when i get the error.

Comment: When you say "first message", you mean the first message after the handshake, right? Have you tried echoing the unmasked client-sent messages on the server side to the screen or to a file to ensure that you're getting what you want?

Comment: I have. I did a `Console.WriteLine(<message>)` and it comes out to be what i send. Right now im sending the word test and statically sending the word test back to the client regardless of what the client sent. and first message means the first message the client sent (in this case Google Chrome).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're including an extra byte at the end of your message.  Shouldn't the line

```
Dim reply(bLength + 1) As Byte
```

be changed to

```
Dim reply(bLength) As Byte
```

instead?  All you need in your message is opcode + length (`frameCount`) + message (`rawData.Length`).  A websocket client will read these bytes as a full, valid message.  It will then read the remaining byte from your message as the start of a new message, effectively corrupting the next message you actually send.

Comment: I have tried that and when i do that i do not get the error but i can only send one message to the client and all prior messages do not  trigger the onmessage event for the websocket.

Comment: Update: I removed the + 1 like you said and instead of the continuous frame error i get a new one `A server must not mask any frames that it sends to the client.` This occurs after i send the second message from the client to the server. second message being after i send the first message after the handshake.

Comment: That implies that the second message you send has the top bit of its second byte set.  This might happen if you had another bit of code sending an extra byte after the first message (meaning that the 129 byte at the start of your next message would be treated as the second byte by the client).  Do you have any other code which sends post-handshake data?  If you can't see anything obvious, it'd be worth using wireshark to see what you're actually sending via the socket.

Comment: I have updated my question with the entire client sub that i use for accepting clients, handshake, and messages. I will also be adding a url to my project files on skydrive soon. Thank you for all your help so far.